# React: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this question has been asked before but I am not sure I understand what's happening here. I have an array of objects that I am mapping in a React component to create a navigation: some element could have children, so I am adding a second .map function for those elements. 
Everything works fine but the second child element is not displayed because it "encounters two children with the same key". Confused...could anyone explain why? I am using the title as key which is now unique.

Here is my items array

```
let navItems = [
  {
    title: "Home",
    href: "/",
    children: []
  },
  {
    title: "Evaluations",
    href: "/evaluations",
    children: [
      {
       id: 1,
       title: "List all evalutions",
       href: "/"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Planner",
        href: "/"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

And here is the code:

```
let items = this.props.items.map((item) => {
  if(item.children.length > 0) {
    return item.children.map((child) => {
      return <li className="menu--item" key={ item.title }>
        <a href={ item.href } className="menu--link">{ item.title }</a>
        <ul className="dropdown">
          <li key={ child.title }><a href="{ child.href}">{ child.title }</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    })
  } else  {
    return <li className="menu--item" key={ item.title }>
      <a href={ item.href } className="menu--link">{ item.title }</a>
    </li>
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are mapping over `item.children` but returning a key with `item.title` inside. `item.title` doesn't change within that loop so you end up with 2 `<li>` elements with a key of "Evaluations". I suspect that you would want to use `map` inside `<ul className="dropdown">`.

```
let items = this.props.items.map((item) => {
  if(item.children.length > 0) {
      return <li className="menu--item" key={ item.title }>
        <a href={ item.href } className="menu--link">{ item.title }</a>
        <ul className="dropdown">
          {item.children.map((child) => {
            return <li key={ child.title }><a href="{ child.href}">{ child.title }</a></li>
          })}
        </ul>
      </li>
  } else  {
    return <li className="menu--item" key={ item.title }>
      <a href={ item.href } className="menu--link">{ item.title }</a>
    </li>
  }
})
```

Comment: Oh yes, I was looping through the same item twice, you are right. I prefer this solution cause don't really wanna add IDs to the array, want to leave it kind of free. Thanks Donovan.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a unique `key` to each element while you are rendering items in an iteration.

Here, you are using `item.title` as the key for the `children` of the item which is same for each child of that item and you are returning an array if `item.children.length > 0` and returning an element in `else` case. I think you should write it like this:

```
let items = this.props.items.map((item) => {
  if(item.children.length > 0) {
    return (
      <div key={item.id}>
        {item.children.map((child) => {
          return (
            <li className="menu--item" key={ child.id }>
              <a href={ item.href } className="menu--link">{ item.title }</a>
              <ul className="dropdown">
                <li key={ child.title }><a href="{ child.href}">{ child.title }</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>  
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  } else  {
    return <li className="menu--item" key={ item.id }>
      <a href={ item.href } className="menu--link">{ item.title }</a>
    </li>
  }
})
```

and there should be an unique id in each navLink like this:

```
let navItems = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: "Home",
    href: "/",
    children: []
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: "Evaluations",
    href: "/evaluations",
    children: [
      {
       id: '2.1',
       title: "List all evalutions",
       href: "/"
      },
      {
        id: '2.2',
        title: "Planner",
        href: "/"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ritesh, you were right. I would rather not add IDs to the array though.

Comment: Then, just make sure `title` do not repeat.